# PHP's configuration setting 'error_log' is not working

Tags: php, error-logging, error-log, selinux

What am I doing wrong here?

I have error_log set in the .ini file along with `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT`.

What else am I missing? This usually gave it to me. I want this set in the .ini file and not in my scripts.

Another interesting thing that is happening is that when I purposefully try and throw an error in one of my scripts, Apache restarts over and over again.

---

This is my event log after one error. Look at the timestamp.

```
Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1700
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Child 1700: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Child 3008: Released the start mutex
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Child 1700: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Child 1700: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:23 2009] [notice] Child 1700: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:24 2009] [notice] Child 3008: All worker threads have exited.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:24 2009] [notice] Child 3008: Child process is exiting
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 128 -- Restarting.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3656
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Child 3656: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Child 3656: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Child 3656: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Child 3656: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:53 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 128 -- Restarting.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3980
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 3980: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 3980: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 3980: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 3980: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 128 -- Restarting.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1600
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 1600: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 1600: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 1600: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:54 2009] [notice] Child 1600: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 128 -- Restarting.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 1068
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Child 1068: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Child 1068: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Child 1068: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Child 1068: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Parent: child process exited with status 128 -- Restarting.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Apache/2.2.14 (Win32) PHP/5.3.0 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Server built: Sep 28 2009 22:41:08
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:55 2009] [notice] Parent: Created child process 3220
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:56 2009] [notice] Child 3220: Child process is running
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:56 2009] [notice] Child 3220: Acquired the start mutex.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:56 2009] [notice] Child 3220: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Wed Nov 04 19:34:56 2009] [notice] Child 3220: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

---

<sub>This has been asked 1000 times and I have browsed through the different posts before posting this, but I have not found an answer. As long as I have been programming with PHP, this have always been a nightmare to get working.</sub>

Comment: Related, for locating the PHP error log: *[Where does PHP store the error log? (PHP 5, Apache, FastCGI, and cPanel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/)* (despite the over-specific title).

Answer (score 25):

#### Check PHP-FPM is not explicitly setting `error_log`:

Make sure the file `/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf` does not contain `php_admin_value` settings for *error_log*. Search for the following and comment them out using a semi-colon:

```
; NOTE: If these are set, ini_set('error_log', 'path') will have no effect
; inside your php code, and this will be forced to be the value always.
; php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
; php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
```

Then restart php-fpm:

```
systemctl restart php-fpm
```

#### Check Apache .htaccess files are not setting the `error_log` value using

`php_admin_value` settings in the Apache configuration files cannot be overridden, so make sure you don’t have any *php_admin_value* for the `error_log` setting in the Apache configuration files. Also check for `php_value` settings just in case.

[PHP Website - How to change configuration settings](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)

Comment: Lifesaver! This solved it for me after spending hours troubleshooting. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

## Flimm's Troubleshooting Guide

Here is my troubleshooting guide to `error_log()` calls not working.

1. Look at your **server's configuration** to find out where the default error log file is.
   This depends on which server you're using. To get you started, have
   a look at Apache's [`ErrorLog` option](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/logs.html#errorlog) if you're using Apache or
   Nginx's [`error_log` option](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) if you're using Nginx. Make sure it
   is set to a file. If you're using a tool like Valet, note that it's
   using server software like Nginx behind the scenes.
2. Check the **permissions of your server's error log file**. On Unix-like systems, it should be writeable by the correct user and group, and the permissions of the parent directory and all its ancestors need to be correct as well. Use `chmod` and `chown`.
3. Check the **configuration of PHP in the `.ini` files**. Specifically, check for `log_errors = On` and `error_reporting = E_ALL | E_STRICT` and `error_log = /tmp/example/php_errors.log` (see docs for [`log_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors), [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [`error_log`](http://php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) configuration settings). To find the `.ini` file, look at the output of `phpinfo();`.  If `error_log` is not set, by default it goes to the error log for the server, mentioned in the previous steps. If `error_log` is set to a file, it should already exist and be writeable, just like in previous steps. Remember to restart the server after configuration changes.
4. Check that **PHP's settings aren't being changed by server configuration**. Your server's configuration (even `.htaccess`) can change PHP configuration settings. In Apache, this is done using `php_admin_value` and `php_admin_flag` ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.php)). For instance, you may find in your `.htaccess` file this line: `php_admin_flag[log_errors] = off`. Remember to restart the server after configuration changes. At this point, you should be able to create a test file `test.php` with the contents `<?php error_log("test");`, restart your server, and open the URL in your browser, and you should be able to see `test` in your error log (either the server's, or the one specified by `error_log =` ). But keep reading.
5. Check that **PHP's settings aren't being changed at run-time**. The `log_errors` option can be changed at runtime by running `ini_set('log_errors', 1);`, and so can the other configuration options `error_reporting` and `error_log`. Also note there is a special [`error_reporting()` PHP function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) which changes the configuration at run-time. Search your code-base for any invocations of `ini_set` or `error_reporting`. WordPress for example does run these depending on the value of `WP_DEBUG`.

Other things to look at: You may be having permission issues in SELinux (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29213286/247696)).

Comment: And one more thing: if you are accessing an https: website, then you need to look in the `ssl_error_log` file and _not_ the `error_log` file.

Comment: @charlesdeb Are you talking about nginx?

Comment: My experience was with apache. I spent ages trying to figure out why nothing was being logged to the `error_log` file any more, and then realised that it was all going to `ssl_error_log` (although some installs send everything to `error_log` whether it is SSL or not.

Comment: In my case the application itself had it's own log files.

Answer (score 11):

You also need to set [`log_errors = On`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.log-errors) in file *php.ini*.

Comment: Hi Chaos, thanks. I already have that set to On. Am I missing anything else?

Comment: Just restart the server.

Comment: @aagjalpankaj Can you explain why did it help and why it was broken?

Comment: Where is file `php.ini` located? `In /etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`?

Comment: OK, one way is the line with "Loaded Configuration File" in the output from `phpinfo()`. From the command line: `php -r "phpinfo();" | grep "Loaded Configuration File"` (sample output: *Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.4/cli/php.ini*). In a web context: If test page file *test.php* exist it contains a call to `phpinfo()` - e.g., URL `http://localhost/test.php` (sample output: */etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini*).

Answer (score 9):

In case anyone else is having trouble getting their local development environment to log errors, here's what fixed it for me:

On Windows, `error_log` must be set to the complete path to the log for `error_log()` to work (`error_log = c:\apache\php_errors.log`). However, if `error_log = php_errors.log` with no path, php will still be able to log startup errors such as

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext\php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found

Comment: I specified full path and did not create the file in advance. When I restart WAMP the log file is created but WAMP display a yellow icon and localhost won't load. Any ideas what that might be? When I comment out `error_log` everything is fine but PHP errors appear in the Apache log.

Answer (score 8):

The problem I ran into was that the error log I had designated was write-protected. All my *.htaccess* settings were correct, but PHP just couldn't write to the error log, because it didn't have any permissions. This fixed it right up for me:

```
chmod 777 watermellon-app-errors.log
```

Obviously, you're going to want to change the *.log* part to whatever file you're using for a log.

Comment: Yes, you're correct. Of course, 644 might not be enough if the file's owner is someone else. You could use 777 to test it, and then lower permissions to see what works.

Comment: In my case, I needed 646.. just FYI in case someone else runs into a problem like me

Comment: On Mac OS, I had to use 666 since the normal files are set up as root:wheel  I probably could have left it 646 since I think apache is running as "_www" by default.

Comment: [chmod 777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777/) = "sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can read, can write and can execute. (O)thers can read, can write and can execute.". How secure is that?

Answer (score 4):

If the [error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) directive is set, the file will be used for recording PHP errors. When it is not set, errors will be logged to the Apache log. Take a look at *[error_log](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log)*.

The error_log file and the directory it's in must be writable by the user that Apache is running under. If the file isn't being created, it's probably due to a permissions issue.

I don't know for sure why Apache would be crashing on you, but I'm guessing it's a permissions issue of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand **why**, but the error log is now working. Here is what I did.

I gave up and commented back out the *error_log* directive and closed the ini file. I ran the script with the parse error to see if Apache would still crash and I got the PHP error in the log file. This is freaky, because the ini file no longer has *error_log* enabled and my script is not using [ini_set()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ini-set.php).

Comment: This is more a question than an answer. [*Stack Overflow* is not a forum](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92115).

Answer (score 2):

In my case, on a [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) development server, after a full `yum update`, the permission on */var/log/http* was changed to [700](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-700/) and the user to 'root', so the user 'apache' wasn't able to enter or write into it.

It was still able to write into the existing file */var/log/httpd/error.log*, but it wasn't able to create a new file, as I use date-suffixed log files.

Issuing the command

```
chown apache /var/log/httpd
```

solved the problem.

Comment: [chmod 700](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-700/) = *"Sets permissions so that, (U)ser / owner can read, can write and can execute. (G)roup can't read, can't write and can't execute. (O)thers can't read, can't write and can't execute."*

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29), [SELinux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security-Enhanced_Linux) (enabled by default) will prevent Apache / httpd from appending errors to your log file even when your file is specified in file *php.ini* and its containing directory has all permissions allowed.

You can see if this is happening by looking at your system log file in **/var/log/messages**

[image]

The ideal solution is to configure SELinux to allow access to the log file.

The quicker solution is to disable SELinux in **/etc/selinux/config** by setting *SELINUX* to disabled.

You'll need to reboot your system after doing this for the change to take effect.

Comment: The advice you gave actually has a website to stop that advice being given. http://stopdisablingselinux.com

Comment: I know, hence my writing "ideal." I'm not yet convinced that a home user working locally needs SELinux turned on.

Comment: If the people at SElinux would stop breaking everything people could bother to use it. Even an SElinux log to say, "Hey, I just blocked this too. This is how you can enable it if you want." would be really helpful. As it is there's no way of knowing why it's broke until you say, it's probably SElinux because they break everything. Basically anything broken, I would look to SElinux until I eventually just gave up because it was taking hours out of my life just diagnosing that it was SElinux or searching for the obscure command or setting to let this instance through.

Answer (score 1):

For further debugging:
`phpinfo();`

It shows the current *error_log* setting, next to the *error_log* value in phpinfo() and can be useful when a vhost isn't logging.

I ended up here after that setting got overridden from file *php.ini* and the vhost. I ended up logging to syslog.

Comment: cheers for the formating and spelling update @PeterMortensen. I've updated it to specify that the error_log value is found under error_log. I'm not sure how much value was gained by this, however thanks for the formating and spelling update.

Comment: i was *sure* i was looking at the right error log, and so never bothered to check phpinfo -- i finally gave up and tried it after i saw you mention vhost. of course, there it was, the path to the real log.

Answer (score 1):

For me, manually creating the file, */var/log/php_error.log*, solved the issue:

1. In file *php.ini*, configure log to file

   ```
   log_errors = On
   error_log = /var/log/php_error.log
   ```
2. Restart Apache

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart apache2
   ```
3. Create the log file, for example:

   ```
   sudo touch /var/log/php_error.log
   ```
4. Give the correct rights (owner must be Apache)

   ```
   sudo chown www-data:root /var/log/php_error.log
   ```

   (And if not already set)

   ```
   sudo chmod 0644 /var/log/php_error.log
   ```
5. Test this way, for example:

   ```
   sudo vim /var/www/.../index.php
   ```

   ```php
   <html>
       <body>
           PHP file:
           <?php
               echo "Hello, World!";
               trigger_error("User error in PHP", E_USER_ERROR);
           ?>
       </body>
   </html>
   ```
6. Check the error is written

   ```
   sudo less /var/log/php_error.log
   ```

Comment: Thank you @Peter Mortensen for making my answer clearer and well-formatted!

Answer (score 0):

As [bradym said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678009/phps-configuration-setting-error-log-is-not-working/1754340#1754340), check whether you have write permissions to the directory where you PHP error log is located for the Apache user. If you created a log file with written permissions it's not enough; the directory should have them too.

Answer (score 0):

The `error_log = "C:\php\Log\error.log"` line was not working for me either. The solution for me was that you shouldn't create the *error.log* yourself, because PHP will do it for you. [See the PHP message board](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php). I'm using PHP 5.2 on a [Windows Server 2008](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_2008) server.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and fixed it by doing this:

```
chmod 0777 -R /var/log/apache2
apachectl restart
```

I think PHP runs as user `www-data` while access to `/var/log/apache2` is limited to `root`. So, this fixes it.

Answer (score -1):

This did the trick for me.

```
setsebool -P httpd_unified 1
```

Please note, this would be the preferred method below to try first:

```
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t 'errorLogNameHere.error.log
restorecon -v 'errorLogNameHere.error.log'
```

This answer was derived from the logs from executing this command line:

```
journalctl -xe
```

Further information on the system I was running on:

PHP 7.0 and [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 7

I am not sure if it's not obvious, but the issue was Apache's configuration to writing files. I did try [chmod 777](https://chmodcommand.com/chmod-777), chmod a+w on the logging directory, but this didn't work for me.

Comment: But `chmod a+w` is not the same as `chmod 777`(?).