# Setting "error_log" location is not taken into account

Tags: php, apache, logging, configuration, error-logging

A similar question has been asked already at *[PHP's configuration setting 'error_log' is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1678009/php-error-log-not-working)*, but that's not my problem.

My `phpinfo();` shows

| Directive | Local Value | Master Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| error_log | /var/opt/remi/php74/log/php-fpm/www-error.log | /var/opt/remi/php74/log/php-fpm/www-error.log |
| max_execution_time | 456 | 456 |

I try to change location to `/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`, however the location always stays on `/var/opt/remi/php74/log/php-fpm/www-error.log` not matter what I am doing

#### File */etc/php.d/impng.ini*

```
max_execution_time = 456
error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
```

I run `systemctl restart httpd` / `systemctl restart php74-php-fpm` several times

I don't see file `/var/opt/remi/php74/log/php-fpm/www-error.log` configured anywhere:

```
$ grep php_admin_value /etc/httpd/conf/*
$ grep php_admin_value /etc/httpd/conf.d/*
$ grep php_admin_value /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*
$ grep php_admin_value /etc/php.d/*
$ grep error_log /etc/php.d/*
/etc/php.d/impng.ini:error_log = /var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
    
$ grep ErrorLog  /etc/httpd/conf/*
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# ErrorLog: The location of the error log file. 
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# If you do not specify an ErrorLog directive within a &lt;VirtualHost> 
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:ErrorLog "logs/error_log"

$ grep ErrorLog  /etc/httpd/conf.d/*
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log

$ grep ErrorLog  /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/*
```

Note, errors are written properly to `/var/opt/remi/php74/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`. Manual logging with `error_log("test", 3, "/var/log/php-fpm/www-error.log");` is also working.

But I don't manage to change the location of `error_log`. Other parameters (e.g., `max_execution_time`) are taken properly into account as expected.

It's a minor issue. I could create symbolic link or simply read file `/var/opt/remi/php74/log/php-fpm/www-error.log`. However, I wonder why I cannot change it.

Comment: Are you sure you are trying to modify the correct configuration file to begin with? What does phpinfo say, which config file(s) were actually read?

Comment: phpinfo list all ini-files in `/etc/php.d/`, include my custom `/etc/php.d/impng.ini` at last one - like expected.

Comment: Also note it makes a difference if you are running php-fpm via browser or running a script manually from CLI. Then the file location could be different.

Comment: Can you [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69160967/edit) (incl. version information for all) operating system, web server, PHP version, default shell, runtime context (web hosting/local), and relevant configuration information?

Comment: @PeterMortensen, see answer below, it shows my configuration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Fedora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) and [RHEL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux) / [CentOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CentOS) 8, PHP is executed via the php-fpm service.

And the log is configured in the pool configuration file.

#### File */etc/opt/remi/php74/php-fpm.d/www.conf*

```
...
; Default Value: nothing is defined by default except the values in php.ini and
;                specified at startup with the -d argument
;php_admin_value[sendmail_path] = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f www@my.domain.com
;php_flag[display_errors] = off
php_admin_value[error_log] = /var/opt/remi/php74/log/php-fpm/www-error.log
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
;php_admin_value[memory_limit] = 128M

; Set the following data paths to directories owned by the FPM process user.
;
; Do not change the ownership of existing system directories, if the process
; user does not have write permission, create dedicated directories for this
; purpose.
;
; See warning about choosing the location of these directories on your system
; at http://php.net/session.save-path
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/opt/remi/php74/lib/php/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/opt/remi/php74/lib/php/wsdlcache
;php_value[opcache.file_cache]  = /var/opt/remi/php74/lib/php/opcache
;php_value[opcache.preload] = /var/www/html/preload/preload.php
;php_value[opcache.preload_user] = apache
```

It has to be configured in the spool file, as each pool may run under a different user, so each needs its own files.

Tips: you can see the configuration files provided by a package using:

```
rpm --query --configfiles php74-php-fpm
```

> /etc/httpd/conf.d/php74-php.conf 
> /etc/logrotate.d/php74-php-fpm 
> /etc/opt/remi/php74/php-fpm.conf 
> /etc/opt/remi/php74/php-fpm.d/www.conf